# Twig namespace class methods

Tags: php, templates, twig

I'm attempting to transition a lightweight MVC framework to use `Twig` as a template engine instead of it just including `php` files in the controller. This would allow me to create multiple website layout folders under one core and allow clients to manipulate the templates.

I've gotten Twig to work, but I have a problem with a namespace and it's classes.

This framework uses it's own namespace in each `template.php` file, which gives access to a multitude of classes. One of them is a localization class, `Localize`, which has a method `string`. I would like to pass all strings in Twig templates through the `Localize::string()` method, but how can I do this?

In the controller I have:

```
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem([$path]);
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
echo $twig->render($file, $data);
```

I tried to use:

```
$loader->addPath($path, 'Namespace');
```

With no luck. In the template:

```
{{ Localize.string('string') }}
```

The method is supposed to return the string or a translation but returns nothing meaning it does not work. Can I somehow add all templates to a namespace as I would

```
<?php namespace Namespace; ?>
```

and have access to Localize::string() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is some way to [extend Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) to use your custom methods.

An example to use your `Localize::string()` function as a Twig filter:

```
// In your controller
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('localize', function ($string) {
    return Localize::string($string);
});

$twig->addFilter($filter);

// Then in your .twig file
{{ 'some_string'|localize }}
```

This will pass the string `'some_string'` to your custom `localize` filter, which then returns `Localize::string('some_string')`.

---

Since the `Twig_SimpleFilter` constructor takes a `callable` as its argument, you could also write `$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('localize', 'Localize::string')`, which might be more readable, depending on who you ask.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. Having to add them as filters. Of course it adds  a layer of protection. Can I chain this somehow, adding multiple Filters in one variable then just calling addfilter($filter) withouth having to call multiple?

Comment: Put them all in an array an then use a `foreach` to add them to the environment. The advantage of using Twig's custom filters and functions functionality is that it decouples the View from your other classes (e.g. `Localize`).